# Substring range break out SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, range, substring, charindex

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
Order/item       Price
2001/1-10        $1000
2001/11-13       $ 500 
2002/1-20 + 22   $2500
2003             $2000
```

And I want to take the data from order/item and create a range to look like this:

```
Order/item
2001/1
2001/2
2001/3
```

and so on...  As you see there can be a '+' sign indicating the range is x-y and also z...

my variable and substring skills are limited. My macro thought is to take the first number after the '/' sign and +1 to it until I get to the 2nd number. But there are also records with no '/' sign and then how to handle the '+' numbers.  Also the first number after the '/' sign could be anywhere from 1-4 digits in length.  Sorry if this is basic.  I know there are similar questions out there but nothing that really helped me understand.

EDIT:

So what about this... not worrying about order/one_item format...  lets say that the field will always be order/item-item with no spaces +'s etc.... I want to take the first item (so all the numbers after'/' but before '-' and then add 1 to it until I reach the 2nd item value. so the table would look like this:

```
order/item    new_col
2001/1-10      1
2001/1-10      2
2001/1-10      3
2001/1-10      4
2001/1-10      5
2001/1-10      6
2001/1-10      7
2001/1-10      8
2001/1-10      9
2001/1-10      10
```

That should probably be easier to do I would think.

Comment: This looks far too comlpex to be achieved (easily and sensibly) in SQL.

Comment: Yes it is complex, and that is fine with me if someone wants to post a complex solution.

Comment: What I mean is, it's a much easier job to do in a programming language (such as C#)

Comment: This should be done via an intermediate table that contains an entry for *each* item ... Ranges like that balloon into horrible nightmares,

Comment: @ Alex, I have a table that has an entry for each item that I'm trying to join with using order/ONE_item...  It's either that or find a way to make that other table match this one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with your simplified version. The CTE generates a (large) range of numbers which is then joined back to the string which has been split up into it's constituent parts.

```
DECLARE @OrderItem VARCHAR(100) = '2001/1-10'

;WITH Nums AS
(
  SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects 

)
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@OrderItem, 0, CHARINDEX('/', @OrderItem)),
        n
FROM nums
WHERE n BETWEEN CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@OrderItem, 6, 100), 0, CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(@OrderItem, 6, 100))) AS INT)
AND CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@OrderItem, 6, 100), CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(@OrderItem, 6, 100))+1, 100) AS INT)
```

So assuming you have a table called `Orders` that has columns called `OrderItem` and `Price`, then you can join them together like this:

```
;WITH Nums AS
(
  SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects 

)

SELECT  SUBSTRING(Orders.OrderItem, 0, CHARINDEX('/', Orders.OrderItem)) AS [Order],
        n AS Item,
        Price
FROM Orders
CROSS APPLY nums
WHERE n BETWEEN CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Orders.OrderItem, 6, 100), 0, CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(Orders.OrderItem, 6, 100))) AS INT)
AND CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Orders.OrderItem, 6, 100), CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING(Orders.OrderItem, 6, 100))+1, 100) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to get the range for each row

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetRange (@range varchar(10))
RETURNS @RangeTable TABLE (RangeNumber int) AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @StartRange int, @EndRange int

    SELECT @StartRange = SUBSTRING(@range, CHARINDEX('/', @range, 0) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', @range, 0) - CHARINDEX('/', @range, 0) - 1),
        @EndRange = SUBSTRING(@range, CHARINDEX('-', @range, 0) + 1, LEN(@range))

    WHILE @StartRange <= @EndRange BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RangeTable (RangeNumber) VALUES (@StartRange)
        SET @StartRange = @StartRange + 1
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

And then join to this in your select for your original table

```
SELECT * FROM OrderItemTable 
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetRange(OrderItem)
```

You could probably modify the GetRange function to handle some of your other situations (+, no range, etc.).